# C++ access violation when calling virtual method

Tags: c++, virtual, access-violation

Whenever I'm calling a virtual method in the GUIElement object, I'm getting an access violation exception. However, when calling "isFinished()", there's no exception.

I'm using Visual Studio 2013.

Here's my code:

Some code of main.cpp:

```
GUIElement* guiElement = NULL;

void init()
{ 
     guiElement = new GUIElement(&b);
}

void draw()
{

     if (guiElement == NULL || !(guiElement->hidesScreen())) //Causes the exception
        currentScreen->draw();
}
```

GUIElement.h

```
#pragma once
class GUIElement
{
public:
    GUIElement(bool* ok);
    ~GUIElement();
    bool isFinished();
    virtual void update(float deltaMs);
    virtual void draw();
    virtual bool pausesScreen();
    virtual bool hidesScreen();
private:
    bool finished;
protected:
    virtual void onFinish();
    bool* ok;
};
```

GUIElement.cpp

```
#include "GUIElement.h"


GUIElement::GUIElement(bool* ok)
{
    this->ok = ok;
}


GUIElement::~GUIElement()
{
}

bool GUIElement::isFinished()
{
    return finished;
}

void GUIElement::onFinish()
{
    finished = true;
}

void GUIElement::update(float deltaMs)
{

}

void GUIElement::draw()
{

}

bool GUIElement::pausesScreen()
{
    return false;
}

bool GUIElement::hidesScreen()
{
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Please also post the code where you are calling the method.

Comment: I did. "//Causes the exception" in the draw method.

Comment: what are you trying to do with this? guiElement = new GUIElement(&b);
this "b" variable does not even exists.

Comment: Are you sure guiElement has not been destroyied?

Comment: If you want others to help you, you should at least bother to create http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Your object has become corrupt or been deleted.

Comment: Tip: PLEASE consider to read the Clean Code book.

Comment: What is `currentScreen`? How is it declared and what is its value during `::draw()` execution?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found the answer myself. Accidentally deleted the guiElement.

Comment: Great if you found the answer. Posting it would help future visitors more than just knowing that one exists.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @msrd0 Could you please clarify your point? How do you imagine OP to request clarification from himself by leaving a comment below his own post?!

Comment: @CiaPan I just said that it doesn't help anybody that you know that the OP has found an answer. SO is not just to help the OP but to help all people with the problem

Comment: @msrd0 Actually, there was no question... Anyway the answer shows at least that one should thoroughly check error conditions before asking other people for explanation, because nobody else can inspect the code and execution environment in which the error occured.

Answer (score 3):

The problem you're seeing usually happens when you're calling a method through an invalid pointer. Virtual methods require a v-table in order to make the call, and the virtual table pointer (usually abbreviated to vptr) is stored in your instance. Because of this the you must point to a valid instance in order for the call not to exhibit undefined behaviour (which in your case is a crash!).

However, not virtual functions do not require the vptr. Also, the compiler is able to determine the function at compile time. I suspect in your call to `isFinished` you'll see that the `this` pointer is either `null` or some garbage value.

If you post the entire `main` we can probably pinpoint exactly where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly `currentScreen` is not what you expect it to be—but it's hard to tell with *that* piece of code.

Comment: No, currentScreen is fine, I'm also getting the exception when calling pausesScreen outside the if.

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem is following line :

```
if (guiElement == NULL || !(guiElement->hidesScreen()))
```

1) Let guiElement == NULL -> is True
2) guiElement->anything fails, because guiElement IS NULL...

Comment: No. If guiElement == NULL, the expression is short-circuited and evaluated to true. The second part is not executed. That said, I am not supporting the very confusing style of this expression - but it does not cause the crash by itself.

Comment: Wrong. The right operand of `||` is not evaluated if the left one returned `true`.